# DotNetOpenMail Authentication Issues

Tags: c#, authentication, smtp, gmail

I'm trying to use DotNetOpenMail in my project due to it's easy to use interface and support for inline attachments. I am having a nightmare using the component with Gmail and Authentication. It reports "Unauthorised authentication type" when I use authentication and also reports "Must issue a STARTTLS command first." when I use it with Gmail.

Has anyone been able to use this component successfully with Gmail and Authentication?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one is giving me the right answer, let me answer my question myself. I discovered that DotNetOpenMail DOES not support SSL, STARTTLS and TLS and so it cannot be used with Gmail.
I ended up using System.Net.Mail which gave me exactly what I was looking for.